# Android layout diagonal cut

Tags: android, android-layout, diagonal

How can I cut a layout (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) diagonally with content inside?

The mockup looks like that:

[image]

I tried using diagonal layout libraries like https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout but I cant seem to get this cut on the right of the image and on the left of the second layout with the library or with a custom View.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can draw the background of every ViewGroup by yourself.

There are some key points in this solution:

1. You need to extend the desired `ViewGroup`:

   ```
   public class DiagonalLayout extends LinearLayout
   ```
2. Override the function:

   [`protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchDraw(android.graphics.Canvas))
3. Fill the method above. Here is the sample code:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       int height = canvas.getHeight();
       int width = canvas.getWidth();
       Path path = new Path();
       path.moveTo(0, 0);
       path.lineTo(width / 3 + width / 10, 0);
       path.lineTo(width / 3 - width / 10, height);
       path.lineTo(0, height);
       path.close();
       canvas.save();
       canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
       canvas.drawColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
       canvas.restore();
       path = new Path();
       path.moveTo(width / 3 + width / 10 + width / 10, 0);
       path.lineTo(width, 0);
       path.lineTo(width, height);
       path.lineTo(width / 3, height);
       path.close();
       canvas.save();
       canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
       Paint paint = new Paint();
       paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.black));
       canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
       canvas.restore();
       super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
   }
   ```

The effect of the code above is:

[image]

What the code above does is:

1. Draw the polygon on the left.
2. Save `Canvas` state, clip `Canvas` to the polygon and fill it with color
3. Restore `Canvas` to original size, draw second polygon

To draw a bitmap, use [`drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint)) method instead of filling it with red color.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the cut orientation and angle is specified with xml attributes:

```
diagonal:diagonal_angle=""
diagonal:diagonal_gravity=""
```

You need to work on **diagonal:diagonal_gravity** in order to create the cut, I've just seen some example but I think that with it you can decide where to cut.

For example: your left block should have `diagonal:diagonal_gravity="right|top"` this should cut from right-top with the angle specified in `diagonal:diagonal_angle`.

You need to compose both block, so you need to play with `LinearLayout` and two `DiagonalLayout`

Let me know if something like this could work:

```
<!-- above this there's an outer Layout block  -->
<!-- This LinearLayout block is to create a container for the images -->
<LinearLayout           
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="orizontal">

    <!-- Left image block -->
    <com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
        android:layout_width="what-you-need"
        android:layout_height="what-you-need"
        app:diagonal_angle="choose"
        app:diagonal_gravity="right|top">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="image" />
    </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

    <!-- Right image block -->
    <com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
        android:layout_width="what-you-need"
        android:layout_height="what-you-need"
        app:diagonal_angle="choose"
        app:diagonal_gravity="left|bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="image" />
    </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Marco
Thanks for your answer. This does not work because it's cutting the edges into a triangle where it should stay there with 4 angles...